# how to access Function and variables of module?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module, yocto

I am currently working on linux modules. We inserted module to the linux kernel. How can we access or manipulate the data that are received by the module?

Is that any possible way to read that values and call that functions in linux?

Comment: If those are exported using `EXPORT_SYMBOL_*()` then there should not be any problem in using it. I suggest to read more about `EXPORT_SYMBOL()` and its family.

Comment: Do you ever to access the data from another kernel module, or from userspace?

Comment: No. actually this is for the first time!!

Comment: You have to consider one of possible interface: IOCTL, sysfs, netlink, ...

Comment: If we export symbol from the module where did they stored to access ?

Comment: Sorry, (my previous comment was auto-corrected by my phone). I meant, do you need to access the data from another kernel module, or from userspace? In the first case `EXPORT_SYMBOL*()`, in the latter case, IOCTL, sysfs, netlink, or read/write using a character device node.

Comment: I need to access from userspace!!